# Program or script to walk directory structure, based on my loop

Tags: command-line, automation, windows-server-2003, archiving, 7-zip

I've the following loop and would like some help expanding it's functionality.

```
for /D %d in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%d.zip" ".\%d\*"
```

Currently, in a directory structure such as below:

**Logfiles > Year > Month > Day > Hours**

I manually navigate to the **Day** directory, execute my 'for' loop in Windows Command Line, and my loop creates zipped directories of each '**Hour**' directory under the chosen **Day**.  I then manually navigate to the next **Day**, and repeat, until I have zipped the whole **Month**.

Environment is Server 2003, I can ONLY use Command Prompt (no PowerShell or scope for installing) and cannot use 3rd party 'solutions'.

***Q1:*** Can I automate this at e.g. Month or even Year level, **preserving the HOURLY zipping**, as that is the whole point...?

***Q2:*** I currently migrate the zipped hourly files to cold storage manually - the directory structure at the destination is slightly different to that at the source.  Is there any scope to automate that as well?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: What is the format for the names of your directories?

Comment: e.g.

AppLogs > 2016 > 01 > 24 > 17 represents 1700hrs on the 24th of January 2016

Comment: "I currently migrate the zipped hourly files to cold storage manually - the directory structure at the destination is slightly different to that at the source" what is the cold storage directory structure?

Comment: OK so for example:

`C:\SomeApp\SubDir1\SubDir2\SubDir3\LogFiles\2016` would contain a year's worth of monthly source directories, each with their own days, and each day with **now** zipped hours PLUS the original directories which have the log files.

`X:\SomeVM\SomeApp\LogFiles\2016` is the destination to where I would like to create and store just the zip files under their correct monthly and daily structures..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Q1: Can I automate this at e.g. Month or even Year level

> preserving the HOURLY zipping, as that is the whole point...?

The way to automate this is to used nested `for` loops.

The solution below is for the Month Level. Use the same approach with another level of nesting for a Year level solution.

Run the following batch file (RecurseDays.cmd) in the Month folder of your choice:

```
@echo off
rem start in a month folder and loop through the days
for /d /r %%d in (*) do (
  rem for each day, change directory to the day
  pushd %%d
  rem loop through the hours
  for /d %%h in (*) do (
    rem zip the hour
    echo "c:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%h.zip" ".\%%h\*"
    )
  rem done with the day, change directory back to the month
  popd
  )
```

Notes:

- Remove the `echo` from the `7z` command when you are happy that the batch files as expected.

---

#### Q2: I currently migrate the zipped hourly files to cold storage manually

> the directory structure at the destination is slightly different to that at the source. Is there any scope to automate that as well?

You could use `robocopy`. The right place would be just after:

```
  rem done with the day, change directory back to the month
```

Here you could migrate all the hour files for all the days in the month you are in. `robocopy` will preserve the directory structure and it also has has an option to move the zip files if that what you want (instead of just copying them).

See the link below for more information.

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /d](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders.
- [pushd](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) - Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command.
- [popd](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) - Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command.
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.

Comment: Worked nearly perfectly - I had to tweak the last zipping argument from `"%%h\*"` to `".\%%h\*"`, so I didn't get a directory inside the zip file named the same.  Thanks for helping to address Q1 so effectively!

Comment: @vixbix Ah. I was wondering why you had the ``.\`` in there. I thought it wasn't needed so I removed it.

Comment: @vixbix Answer updated to address Q2.